# Convert date in string(Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014) to java.util.date in JAVA

Tags: java, date, mfc, datetime-format

I want to convert this (Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014) Date in string to java.util.Date in java how can I do it. I want the date in the following format.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
```

Actually the Date (Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014) is argument from MFC application which will be launching a executable jar file and the date in string will be its argument. MFC Code that will launch the executable jar. with argument.

```
CString csCurrentTime = CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%a %b %X %Z %Y");
    TRACE(csCurrentTime);
    if (CreateProcess(m_csJrePath, TEXT(" -jar DbxUpldDwnld.jar %s",csCurrentTime), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOA)&siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Please install Java Runtime Environment(JRE) on your PC\n Or JRE not found on given path in INI File."), MB_ICONERROR);
        CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
        return;
    }
```

Also will it be possible to get the date with spaces as single argument in java.
Please Help me, am new to MFC.

Comment: What's the problem? Just use the SimpleDateFormat you created to parse/write the Data String?

Comment: @TimB will it work with the date format I have provided from my MFC application ?

Comment: When you tried it did it work? Your format string does look wrong (it has milliseconds, etc) but all you need to do is go through the javadoc for the format string and work out what you need to match what you are being given. The only thing that might be iffy is matching the timezone but even that looks close enough to work.

Comment: @TimB have tried following code.
    'if(arg[0] != null){
   localModTime = arg[0];
   try {
     
    Date date = formatter.parse(localModTime);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
   
   } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }'

Comment: Got error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Jan 16:36:53 India Standard Time 2014"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
 at GetNewFile.main(GetNewFile.java:64)

Comment: Perhaps most for late-comers to the question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014* Is it true that your string contains no day of month? Which Monday of January 2014 do you want, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use another `SimpleDateFormat` that has the format of your time-string to do the parsing. For your example, this one should work:

```
String time = "Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
System.out.println(formatter.format(parser.parse(time)));
```

As @TimB points out, all the date and time patterns can be found in [the JavaDoc for `SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: The code works for me but the problem I am facing now is its showing output as '2014-01-06T16:20:12.000Z' but today's date is '2014-01-13' and its showing '2014-01-06' how can this be resovled.

Comment: :Thanks mate your answer came as blessing to me :)

Comment: Tue Jun 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) i want only date from this string. Is it possible? and this string is getting from js.

Comment: This answer isn’t correct. Since in January 2014 India was 5 hours 30 minutes ahead of UTC and since the trailing `Z` in the result means UTC, the correct time of day of the output would be 10:50:12. Your code printed `2014-01-06T11:50:12.000Z`, so wrong by one hour.

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

### Update:

Thanks to Ole V.V.

For a more general solution, replace `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDayOfMonth())` with `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1)` which will also simplify the solution by removing the need to obtain the `LocalDate` first.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()                              
                                .appendPattern("E MMM H:m:s")
                                .appendLiteral(' ')
                                .appendZoneText(TextStyle.FULL)
                                .appendLiteral(' ')
                                .appendPattern("u")
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1)                                
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014",
                    "Mon Feb 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }        
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-01-06T16:20:12+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
2014-02-03T16:20:12+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

### Original answer:

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using the modern API:**

Your date-time string does not have day-of-month. It means that you need to provide a day-of-month to the `DateTimeFormatter` which you can do by using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-). In order to obtain the first *Monday* of the month, the idiomatic way is to use [`TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#firstInMonth-java.time.DayOfWeek-).

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Mon Jan 16:20:12 India Standard Time 2014";

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2014, Month.JANUARY, 1)
                                .with(TemporalAdjusters.firstInMonth(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDayOfMonth())
                                .appendPattern("E MMM H:m:s")
                                .appendLiteral(' ')
                                .appendZoneText(TextStyle.FULL)
                                .appendLiteral(' ')
                                .appendPattern("u")
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-01-06T16:20:12+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>